# How to scale tables at different resolutions

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-table

Here is my website: http://livyscupcakery.bitballoon.com/

On mobile versions (I'm looking at the site with an iPhone 5) the tables on the 'Products' and 'Contact' page don't look good on anything other than my screen resolution (~2000x1000) on Chrome.

I'd like some help on how to scale the 'Products' table so it is fixed to the box around it and adjusts itself on different resolutions (so for example, on some resolutions there is only one row, and then two rows and then three). Then again, on the 'Contact' page on mobile, the buttons are in a row instead of a column. I'm guessing these two issues are quite similar and can be fixed with the same code.

I started coding a couple of months ago, and I'm really new to this. Please let me know if you need the code to the site to help. Thank you so much.

Comment: try jquery [footable](http://fooplugins.com/footable-demos/) for this

Comment: Bootstrap column layout is easy solution for such task and is proven reliable by many use cases :) I'd recommend it as a out-of-the-box solution.

Answer (score 2):

This would be very easy with `display:table` on the parent element and `display:table-cell` on the children elements.

So for the **contact page** you add this CSS **under** the other styles:

```
// apply these styles at max-width:666px
// or remove the media queries and keep this code instead of your old code.
// keep in mind that if you use this you may have to adjust a few things
// for it to look as smooth as possible transition-wise.

@media only and screen (max-width:666px) { 
    table {
        display:block;
        margin:0;
        margin-top:15px;
        width:100%;
    }
    tbody {
        width:100%;
        display:table;
    }
    .button2 {
        top:0px;
        margin:0;
    }
    td.row2 {
        padding:0;
        display:table-cell;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that your code isn't efficient for this, so I based my code upon your code. The basics are to have `display:table` on the parent element and `display:table-cell` on the children elements. While keeping all elements `width:100%`. Hope this helps.

**Output image:**

[image: Responsive buttons]

**Which can get as small as:**

[image: Responsive buttons as small as possible]

Comment: table { display:block; } is good idea ... but how this solution will be in products page ?? over there is the real problem

Comment: He could use multiple table rows: `<tr>` with `display:table` and add table cells `<td>` with `display:table-cell` for the amount of needed content. More ideally you would do this with `display:inline-block` (or `float:left`) so that it gets automatically pushed down to a new row. And you don't need to bother with the amount of rows and elements per row.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to make your website responsive.

In this case, I would strongly recommend using a responsive web framework such as [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com), [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/), [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/), etc.

These frameworks are developed to make our lives as web developers much easier.

If you do take my advice and decide to pick up a framework, I would recommend using their grid system instead of tables for the layout of your products page.

If not, you can look into media queries [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). Its CSS codes that only run on given criteries (Eg: Screen sizes that are less than 500px in width).

Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

first you can use responsive framework

include bootstrap by add this like to head of your file .

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

then for products add them inside this code 
each product inside this block .

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
    your product code here ... 
</div>
```

Comment: "first you need responsive framework" is not true, you can code it yourself too. It's something you suggest, not something that's necessary.

Comment: he is new to programming and make the website in tables ... what will be better for him a framework or code it your self ... I said First not the only solution .

Comment: What you write in the comment should be included in your answer then, because it's not 'necessary' for more advanced developers. Now your answer says you NEED a responsive framework in order to accomplish it. @Alan's answer does this really well. It's something necessary for other people who would read your answer to understand they have that choice, but it's not a must. That's why it bothers me a bit :)

Comment: As you can see on my answer it's not needed to have a responsive framework for this, as long as you understand responsive CSS. I didn't mean to overcomplicate things. So sorry if you feel annoyed in any way. I'm glad you're willing to help but on the other hand I also like to have answers on StackOverflow that are as clear as possible, so that whenever someone else finds an answer knows exactly what's necessary and what's optional/suggested.